# ArcGIS/ArcPy gets XY backwards?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, wgs84, arcgis-10.6

Okay, this has been bugging me for a long time, but I've always been too embarrassed to ask given how basic a question it is. Do the data access cursors get XY backwards when you use tokens like SHAPE@XY, SHAPE@X, SHAPE@Y, etc? When I use this code:

```
>>> sr = arcpy.SpatialReference ("WGS 1984")
>>> with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor ("layer", ["SHAPE@XY", "XY_Coordinates"], "", sr) as curs:
...     for xy, out in curs:
...         row = [xy, str (xy)]
...         curs.updateRow (row)
```

...I get these types of results:

`(-122.09828731902067, 37.09730805886089)`

[image]

I plug those coordinates into Google Maps and it can't find the location (note I remove the parentheses first). I use this code to flip the coordinates:

```
>>> with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor ("layer", ["SHAPE@XY", "XY_Coordinates"], "", sr) as curs:
...     for xy, out in curs:
...         row = [xy, "{}, {}".format (xy[1], xy[0])]
...         curs.updateRow (row)
```

...and all is copesetic.

[image]

Did ESRI get this wrong or am I missing something completely fundamental to XY coordinates?

Comment: Latitude is a Y value. While some interfaces take lat,lon inputs (Y,X), marking this as "XY" is incorrect.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks @Vince! Interesting that WGS format is Y, X.

Comment: When I think "X,Y" I would intuitively think Longitude,Latitude because as @Vince says "Y" is Latitude. But when I fire off coordinates to the Google Directions API I have to flip them so they are fed to the API as Latitude,Longitude. May be it's Google that is at odds?

Comment: @Hornbydd ESRI-based mapping services also want coordinates in the lat-lon format.

Comment: I've faced this developing tools all the time. With a PCS, the inputs need to be XY, because YX is never going to make sense, but with a GCS, in a context where Lat,Lon is expected, using XY can be counter-intuitive.  The key to making it work is *documenting* the parameters as "X,Y" or "Lat,Lon", to eliminate the confusion (among those that read the documentation, at least).

Comment: According to the WMS (1.3.0)  specification `The Layer CRS has two axes, denoted x and y. The x axis is the first axis in the CRS definition, the y axis is the second axis. Depending on the particular CRS, the x axis may or may not be oriented West-to-East, and the y axis may or may not be oriented South-to-North. The WMS portrayal operation shall account for axis order, origin and direction in the Layer CRS when projecting geographic information from a Layer CRS to the Map CS.`  For EPSG:4326 (https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/4326) the first axis is Latitude... or X

Comment: Yeah, it takes a committee to declare that the "X" axis may be North-South.